# Google Apps Script Exception Error The number of rows in the range must be at least 1

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, exception, triggers

How can I eliminate the exception errors when conditions aren't met below.

My script to move a row from one tab to another works correctly when the condition is met, but when it's not met I get the following error. "Exception: The number of rows in the range must be at least 1.
CIO2365 @ Code.gs:6".  I have the script set up to a trigger, so would like to eliminate the error if possible.

```
function CIO2CIO(){
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ss = sh.getSheetByName("Response Landing");
  const outSheet = sh.getSheetByName('CIO to CIO');

  let data = ss.getRange(2,1,ss.getLastRow()-1,21).getValues();
  let out = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    if (data[i][2] == 'CIO to CIO'){
      out.push(data[i]);
      ss.deleteRow(i+2);
      data.splice(i,1);
      i--;
    }else{return}
  }
  outSheet.getRange(outSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,out.length,21).setValues(out);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I saw your script and error message, I thought that the reason for your error might be due to `ss.getLastRow()` being smaller than 1. If my understanding is correct, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
let data = ss.getRange(2,1,ss.getLastRow()-1,21).getValues();
```

#### To:

```
const lastRow = ss.getLastRow();
if (lastRow <= 1) return;
let data = ss.getRange(2, 1, lastRow - 1, 21).getValues();
```